# ExoPlayerImplInternal: Stop failed. java.lang.IllegalStateException - on API Level 22 and below

Tags: android, stream, http-live-streaming, exoplayer

I have a problem with HLS streams on devices Android 22 Api and below for cameras with high definition 2688x1520 and bitrate 5812 - stream can't play. I use ExoPlayer version 2.9.6 (also testing with 2.10.4). On other devices and other cameras - all ok. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Short logs:

```
D: NoSupport [codec.profileLevel, avc1.4D4032, video/avc] [OMX.google.h264.decoder, video/avc] [generic_x86_64, Android SDK built for x86_64, unknown, 22]
I: Using client-side OMX mux.
E: [OMX.google.h264.decoder] storeMetaDataInBuffers failed w/ err -1010
E: [OMX.google.h264.decoder] ERROR(0x80001001)
E: signalError(omxError 0x80001001, internalError -2147483648)
E: Codec reported err 0x80001001, actionCode 0, while in state 6
E: Internal runtime error.
    java.lang.IllegalStateException
        at android.media.MediaCodec.native_dequeueOutputBuffer(Native Method)
        at android.media.MediaCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer(MediaCodec.java:1033)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.drainOutputBuffer(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1287)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.render(MediaCodecRenderer.java:663)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.doSomeWork(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:536)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:303)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
E: Stop failed.
    java.lang.IllegalStateException
        at android.media.MediaCodec.native_stop(Native Method)
        at android.media.MediaCodec.stop(MediaCodec.java:628)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.releaseCodec(MediaCodecRenderer.java:608)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.video.MediaCodecVideoRenderer.releaseCodec(MediaCodecVideoRenderer.java:508)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.onDisabled(MediaCodecRenderer.java:562)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.video.MediaCodecVideoRenderer.onDisabled(MediaCodecVideoRenderer.java:377)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.BaseRenderer.disable(BaseRenderer.java:153)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.disableRenderer(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:983)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.resetInternal(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:771)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.stopInternal(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:742)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:358)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
D: java.lang.IllegalStateException
```

Link issue on github with full bug report

https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/6433

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> NoSupport [codec.profileLevel, avc1.4D4032, video/avc]

Your video uses H.264 Main Profile (`avc1.4D`) which is not supported by these particular devices. The [minimum requirement](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats#video-formats) for Main Profile is 6.0+. You could check if there's another software decoder available (see [MediaCodecSelector](https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/mediacodec/MediaCodecSelector.html)), although ExoPlayer will pick the best one.